# Is there a method, analogous to the regular rep of a group, which makes a group rep carried on a vector space with an indefinite metric?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I am messing about with a program that decomposes a finite group $G$ into irreps carried on a vector space with indefinite metric. The usual way of decomposing a finite group into irreps is to set up the regular rep $U(g)|h\rangle=|gh\rangle$ with $g,h,k \in G$. The matrices of the regular rep are then,
$$
U(g)^{k}_{h}=\delta^{k}_{gh}
$$
Using the fact that an invariant Hermitian matrix can be diagonalised, it is relatively straightforward to compute a transformation,
$$
T^{\{a,i,u\}}\ _{g}
$$
that maps the regular rep into irreps. In the transformation, $\{a,i,u\}$ is a composite label. "a" labels the inequivalent irreps, "i" labels states within irrep "a" and "u" labels the copies of irrep "a".

I would like to extend this calculation to work with a group rep carried on a vector space with an indefinite metric. Unfortunately, the regular rep is only unitary with respect to a Euclidean metric. So, to test the program, I need some method of taking a group such as $S_{3}$ and making a rep which is carried on a vector space with an indefinite metric (say) $\mbox{diag}=(1,1,1,-1,-1,-1)$. Does anyone know of a way of routinely making a rep of a group carried on a vector space with an indefinite metric?

Answer (score 1):

There is some interaction between the representation and the group. For instance, on an (absolutely) irreducible representation, there can exist at most one invariant symmetric bilinear form (up to a scalar constant). That can happen only when the representation is self-dual, and even in that case there might only be anti-symmetric invariant forms.

If the representation is not absolutely irreducible there is more flexibility (you can have non-equivalent bilinear forms, of different types even), but still it's not possible in general to impose any type of invariant form.

Obviously if you just want any representation with a fixed invariant form, then you can take the trivial action of you group, which clearly leaves this forms invariant, but I assume that is not what you want to do.

Maybe you want to classify all invariant symmetric forms on the regular representation? (I'm not 100% sure what you want to do exactly.)